# Full screen bitmap becomes pixelated on TAB 10.1

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, paint, pixel

I'm drawing a full screen bitmap on my canvas and the jpg I'm using is the native resolution of the TAB 10.1 (1280x752 .. Also tried 1280x800 which is the size including the bottom menu)

But the picture becomes very pixelated on the screen even though no scaling should be taking place

This is [the picture I use for this test](http://i42.tinypic.com/fu2s9e.jpg) and [this is the result on the TAB](http://i40.tinypic.com/206kdwp.jpg)

Here's the code I use :

```
Rect rct = new Rect( 0, 0, 1280, 752 );
canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap, null, rct, lPaint );
```

Any ideas why the picture is not being shown as it should?

Comment: Strange.. when I make a bitmap.getWidth() and a bitmap.getHeight() on my bitmap it returns 640x400 which is 50% of the size that it is native..

Comment: Appearently Android scales down the images on load if they're placed in the normal drawable folders, but if placing them in a folder called drawable-nodpi it dont 

I seriously find alot of this stuff very bizarre.. I mean, why would android wanna cut a 1280x800 images that fits a big display in half onload and make it look like crap.. I dont get it

Answer (score 2):

Try following before using your lPaint:

```
lPaint = new Paint();
lPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
lPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
lPaint.setDither(true);
```